# How to run a while loop in python using a Lambda

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to learn Python and currently studying while loops and I am embarrassed to even ask this question cause I feel I should be able to do this, but I am very confused.

```
def summation(n, term):
    """Return the sum of numbers 1 through n (including n) wíth term applied to each number.
    Implement using recursion!

    >>> summation(5, lambda x: x * x * x) # 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3
    225
    """
    assert n >= 1
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"

    counter = 1
    while counter <= n:
```

Also if there is any suggestions on where to practice while loops etc I will take any and all feedback, I have tried to google this but I cannot find anything.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, and we're not going to do your homework for you. But, for a couple of notes: You shouldn't need to use a lambda. You're being *given* a function which may be a lambda. And the instructions say to use recursion, so there also shouldn't be a `while` loop present in your code.

Comment: `Implement using recursion!` I think your instructor wants you to try solving this using recursion, and not a loop. Are you sure you're looking for a loop-based solution?

Comment: Yes I am positive its supposed to be a while loop. I am learning programming on my own and was looking at recursion on this and I couldn't figure it out. So I was thinking if I make it a while loop maybe that will help me work on using recursion to solve it

Comment: Recursion is just a function that keeps calling itself til some condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it with a while loop:

```
def summation_while(n, term):
    assert n >= 1
    counter = 1
    total = 0
    while counter <= n:
        total += term(counter)
        counter += 1
    return total
```

Test:

```
summation_while(5, lambda x: x**3)
```

Output:

```
225
```

You can also do this by summing a generator expression:

```
def summation_generator(n, term):
    return sum(term(i) for i in range(1, n+1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I will put this in Python tutor and go through it.... 

I dunno why but Python is really hard to me, I have been using Scrimba for HTML, CSS and JS but I found an online course for CS that uses Python and I thought maybe learning some concepts in CS would help but I am struggling hard. 

Do you have any suggestions on best place to practice Python While Loops?

Comment: I did update but I got this back (I am brand new to this stuff), "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: ok I upvoted the question so it should work now